# Are there conditional blocks in GNU Radio?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I was wondering if there was a way to use If statements and such in Gnu Radio without having to go into the generated code. For example if you have a probe and if the value of said probe is 1, branch off to some blocks, and if the value of the probe is 0, branch off to another set of blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use probes to inspect signals. That is broken by design; if you want some stream to depend on another stream, threshold the "controlling" one (so that it is either 0 or 1) and then multiply with the other.